# What is wrong with this recursive quadtree/subdivision algorithm?

Tags: python, recursion, pygame, quadtree

this function is supposed to find if there is above a set number of points within the window, and if there is draw a rectangle around it and then subdivide by recursively calling the same function on all four quadrants of the previous rectangle. The behaviour seems almost right for the first 2 recursions and then seems to go a bit awry.. I also set a max depth so that it dosn't recurse too long. Im using pygame to draw the rectangles on the screen. Im assuming I have got muddled in my logic somewhere.

```py
def recursion(x,x2,y,y2,max):
    #draws a square
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,(0,255,255),(x,y,x2,y2),1)

    currentMax = 0
    total_points = 0
    if max >= 30:
        return None
    currentMax = max + 1
   
    for i in range(len(xlist)):
        if xlist[i] in range(x,x2) and ylist[i] in range(y,y2):
            total_points += 1
    if total_points > 3:
      recursion(int(x),int(x2/2),int(y),int(y2/2),currentMax)#top_left
      recursion(int(x2/2),int(x2),int(y),int(y2/2),currentMax)#top_right
      recursion(int(x),int(x2/2),int(y2/2),int(y2),currentMax)#bottom_left 
      recursion(int(x2/2),int(x2),int(y2/2),int(y2),currentMax)#bottom_right
```

I also call it once to start the recursion with:

```py
recursion(int(0),int(1000),int(0),int(1000),0)
```

The points are generated using:

```py
for i in range(5):
    xlist.append(random.randint(0,1000))
    ylist.append(random.randint(0,1000))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When drawing a rectangle with [`pygame.draw.rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html) you have to specify the top, left point and the width and height instead of the bottom right point.
Furthermore, the computation of the center is wrong. A maximum depth of 30 (2^30) is far too much and you can use the `//` (floor division) operator.

Start with `max >= 5` and `total_points >= 1`:

```py
def recursion(x,x2,y,y2,depth):
    if depth >= 5:
        return
    depth += 1
   
    total_points = 0
    for i in range(len(xlist)):
        if x < xlist[i] <= x2 and y < ylist[i] <= y2:
            total_points += 1

    if total_points >= 1:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,255,255), (x, y, x2-x, y2-y), 1)
        centerx = (x+x2) // 2
        centery = (y+y2) // 2
        recursion(x,       centerx, y,       centery, depth)
        recursion(centerx, x2,      y,       centery, depth)
        recursion(x,       centerx, centery, y2,      depth)
        recursion(centerx, x2,      centery, y2,      depth)
```

---

Minimal example:

[image]

```py
import pygame, random

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def recursion(x,x2,y,y2,depth):
    if depth >= 5:
        return
    depth += 1
   
    total_points = 0
    for i in range(len(xlist)):
        if x < xlist[i] <= x2 and y < ylist[i] <= y2:
            total_points += 1

    if total_points >= 1:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,255,255), (x, y, x2-x, y2-y), 1)
        centerx = (x+x2) // 2
        centery = (y+y2) // 2
        recursion(x,       centerx, y,       centery, depth)
        recursion(centerx, x2,      y,       centery, depth)
        recursion(x,       centerx, centery, y2,      depth)
        recursion(centerx, x2,      centery, y2,      depth)

xlist = []
ylist = []
for i in range(5):
    xlist.append(random.randrange(screen.get_width()))
    ylist.append(random.randrange(screen.get_height()))

screen.fill(0)
recursion(0, screen.get_width(), 0, screen.get_height(), 0)
for p in zip(xlist, ylist):
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255, 0, 0), p, 8)
pygame.display.flip()
#pygame.image.save(screen, "grid.png")

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False 

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Comment: Thank you for the very high quality answer!, I still have some slight confusion and maybe it is because I have misinterpreted what my own code does. How come both our code end up drawing rectangles, considering the code splits each section into 4 equal squares if points are found? When looking at similar quadtree style grouping algorithms they only seem to produce squares.

It also appears like there is some unessecery subdivision occuring in squares with no points present.

Comment: @quak e.g.: `x=4` and `x2=8`. The center is **not** `int(x/2)` (=2) but it is `(x+x2)/2)` (=6)

Comment: @quank77 When drawing a rectangle with [`pygame.draw.rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html) you have to specify the top, left point and the width and height instead of the bottom right point.